# Unusual differences between res.sendFile(file) and express.static(file)

Tags: node.js, express, static

I'm making a web app where I can just upload some Three.js virtual reality projects that I've made and serve them to the browser.

When I began making it, I ran a quick test of my VR folder to see if it was possible. The code worked and so I began spending a lot of time developing the app. The code I used is as follows:

```
app.use('/', express.static('/Users/virtuload-beta/backend/uploads/065fe1658b1374605f31d100eb1e7a1a1568654427336/Nancy_Collins_118226967_v2/'))
```

This worked just fine and the browser rendered my VR scene. I also wanted to make sure the file could be served dynamically (e.g. a user clicking on which VR scene to render with href leading to the url), so I executed the following code which also worked fine:

```
const filepath = '065fe1658b1374605f31d100eb1e7a1a1568654427336/Nancy_Collins_118226967_v2/'
app.use('/', express.static(`/Users/virtuload-beta/backend/uploads/${filepath}`))
```

I am mostly finished the app now, except I have a huge issue, when I serve the VR folders with the index.html file specified (which you need to do with res.sendFile) the browser cannot read the files within the folders and I just get red errors.

My function doesn't serve it as a static file anymore, it gets the id from the url, find the file path from mongodb, as follows:

```
const servepath = (req, res, next) => {
    let id = req.params.id
    Upload.findById(id)
      .populate('Upload')
      .select('relPath') //relPath = /folder/subfolder
      .exec(function (err, upload) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err)
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          const dir = path.join(__dirname, '..', '../vr/uploads')
          const filepath = `${upload.relPath}`
          const fulldir = path.join(dir, filepath)
          console.log(fulldir)
              try {
                    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: `${fulldir}`});

                }
              }
              catch (e) {
                console.error(e)
              }
          // return next();
        }
      })
}
```

The browser is finding the html file, but unable to parse the JS files with it:

GET http://localhost:3000/api/5d8b74be2af25086ab77fef7/js/three.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
vr:21 GET http://localhost:3000/api/5d8b74be2af25086ab77fef7/js/OrbitControls.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
vr:22 GET http://localhost:3000/api/5d8b74be2af25086ab77fef7/js/GLTFLoader.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
vr:23 GET http://localhost:3000/api/5d8b74be2af25086ab77fef7/js/FBXLoader.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
vr:24 GET http://localhost:3000/api/5d8b74be2af25086ab77fef7/js/inflate.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
vr:25 GET http://localhost:3000/api/5d8b74be2af25086ab77fef7/js/WebGL.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
vr:118 GET http://localhost:3000/api/5d8b74be2af25086ab77fef7/MainScene.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

When I hard code the file path into the first line of code I specified here (express.static), the vr renders perfectly... I've tried to serve the files as static files but you cannot do that dynamically, hence the name 'static' files..  does anyone know why this is happening?

I don't know much about headers, could my lack of knowledge on headers be the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `servepath` handler apparently handles requests for `GET /api/:id`. When the browser receives the content of the `index.html` matching the `id` param, it probably finds references expressed as *relative* paths like `<script src="js/three.js">`. To build the *fully qualified* address to this resource, it uses the location of the current file. Which, in the case of the `index.html` you show, seems to be `http://localhost:3000/api/5d8b74be2af25086ab77fef7`.

A (quite) quick way of fixing this would be to:

- expose your projects statically (with `express.static` on the common folder to all your uploads which apparently ends with `/vr/uploads` now)
- then, instead of serving the `index.html` directly from `/api/:id`, use this route as a redirection to the proper static location

Something like that:

```js
// expose all uploads, under the URL http://localhost:3000/uploaded-projects/*
app.use(
  '/uploaded-projects',
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../vr/uploads'))
);
// handler to match a Mongo project ID with a public path under /uploaded-projects
app.get(`/api/:id`, (req, res) => {
  Upload.findById(req.params.id)
  .populate('Upload')
  .select('relPath')
  .exec((err, data) => {
    // ko: explicitly use an HTTP status otherwise it's 200
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
    // ok: tell browser 302 + proper Location header
    res.redirect(`/uploaded-projects/${data.relPath}/index.html`);
  });
});
```

With maybe a bit more effort, you could alter your front-end so that, instead of using the ID in your list of projects, you use `relPath` (which you can provide to the front-end, since you already provide IDs and this `relPath` is inside the Mongo document) and a hard-coded path to the static tree (in my sketch, `/uploaded-projects`). This would allow the front-end to directly build the proper URL, hence avoiding to contact the server for a 302 and you could get rid of this `/api/:id` route.